# The images from Bumblebee 2 is noisy

Tags: ros, bumblebee2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I capture an image from Bumblebee 2 (mono8 from mono 16 raw data).
It looks like that: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54750216/left.jpg
It looks very noisy. Are they supposed to noisy like that ? Or have to adjust some parameters?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198053/the-images-from-bumblebee-2-is-noisy/) by [lood339](https://answers.ros.org/users/20903/lood339/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-23**:
I haven't used the bumblebee before, but that looks sort of like a raw bayer-pattern image. Have you tried passing it through a debayering node/nodelet?

**Comment by [lood339](https://answers.ros.org/users/20903/lood339/) on 2014-11-23**:
I tried to do debayering. But it returns error. My understanding is that mono image does not need to do debayer? Am I right?
I do err = dc1394_deinterlace_stereo_frames(frame, &decodeFrame, DC1394_STEREO_METHOD_INTERLACED);
it returns success.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-24**:
I'm not familiar with the API you're referring to. You may want to consult the manufacturer's docs or wait for someone more knowledgeable to come along.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-24**:
Also... is this actually related to ROS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@ahendrix is right, the first image is a bayer pattern, and the other image posted looks as if the data stream was not correctly gathered or that different color channels are shown in grayscale.

We implemented a driver for a Bumblebee 2 camera some time ago. We are still using and maintaing it. I recommend you that you run it and see what happens. The node is available at http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394stereo .

Run the stereo_camera.launch together with an stereo_image_proc node and subscribe with an image_viewer. If the problem persists I would contact PointGrey support.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1